# Why there is proxy in front of Router (or between PC and Router)?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, proxy, wireless-router

Our company's router is 192.168.135.254

with `traceroute`, I got this:

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.162 (192.168.0.162)  1.903 ms  0.839 ms  0.699 ms
 2  192.168.135.254 (192.168.135.254)  308.121 ms  6.839 ms  4.661 ms
```

SO router is 2, before router there's a `192.168.0.162`, which by `nmap`, I know its a squid proxy,

Why there is a proxy before router?

Is my understanding right? packet from my PC SHOULD first go to router, then go to outside?

Comment: Perhaps it is the companies network switch that controls all the routers and ethernets?

Comment: A switch should not produce an added hop. The Squid proxy might simply be there to enable access to your company's intranet. If you have any questions about your company's network, it would be best to ask your sysadmin. Because Super User is not intended for corporate IT support questions (see the [help/on-topic]), I am voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: Kind of need to know your IP address and routing setup to answer this (run ifconfig -a and route -n).  But it wouldn't be unusual to configure the squid proxy server as the default gateway in a small network, and then use IP tables to redirect 80/443 traffic to squid.  It's called [transparent proxying] (http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy.html).

Comment: Squid is proxy software.  A router is anything that routes packets.  So the device that has Squid installed is also a router.  There are no rules that define where you should have a router.  The device that is running squid could serve many purposes, proxy, firewall, intrusion detection etc.  There is no way to answer this question, other than to go talk to the admins.

Comment: @Paul But why the squid's IP is different from router's ip? by `arp -a` I can find router's MAC but cannot find squid's MAC. I'm just trying to understand network tools/knowledges :)

Comment: This isn't the ideal place for generalised learning, it is for questions that can have specific answers.  The squid box *is* a router, and so is the router.  It is common to have a firewall as the first hop before the internet facing router.  A firewall is also a router.

Comment: Just a point of terminology; tracert implementations use ICMP echo packets, with increasing TTL values, to enumerate devices, by asking them to respond with a TTL EXCEEDED message. Generally when people talk about "Proxies" they are referring to Application-layer intermediaries, and the application has control of which and how to use the "proxy". This is why, in Windows, it is easy to set a web-proxy for HTTP and other web protocols, but very difficult to use a proxy for DNS resolution. My point is, that ICMP is usually directed by Routing, not "proxies" in common parlance. just my 2bits.

Answer (score 0):

Squid proxies serve a couple of purposes, typically.

One is (with SquidGuard) web filtering/blocking, if any. If this is causing you a problem at work, bring it up with IT if it's a legitimate work-related thing it's causing a problem with, and otherwise stop trying to go places that are banned at work if you know what's good for you - they have a little list, and you'll be on it, along with there you were trying to go.

Another is the basic web cache function to reduce load on the outside line and load things that have already been downloaded quickly on the internal network without wasting time & data downloading them again from the external network. With a large cache, this can make a HUGE difference for big repetitive stuff like software updates.